# Chef: Define same attribute with different values for different cookbooks

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Say I have a project to deploy with a template like:
project/file.erb

```
node['simpe_test_value']
```

I want to be able to write 2 different cookbooks to deploy the same project but with different value for the attributes being used in the template, like:

cookbooks/test1/recipes/default.rb

```
node.default['simple_test_value'] = 'in cookbook test 1'
template "project/test.cfg" do
  local true
  source "project/test.erb"
end
```

cookbooks/test2/recipes/default.rb

```
node.default['simple_test_value'] = 'in cookbook test 2'
template "project/test.cfg" do
  local true
  source "project/test.erb"
end
```

Chef will evaluate all the attributes before the converge phase, and so my template file is expanded with the same value for both resources.

**How can I achieve this?**

My goal is to use the same code for a project and deploy it multiple times (different cookbooks/different recipes) by adjusting only some attributes.

Comment: Are you targetting the same node ? If yes you'll have to use the variables attributes of template resource. (I will give an exemple if you're effectively targetting the same node)

Comment: Yes, I am targeting the same node.  Note that I have provided a very basic example, in my infrastructure this goes a bit more complex using a custom LWRP which will call the template, so at the end, the template resource being used is the same for all of them. I have been thinking on defining a custom dictionary in a ruby_block and pass that into the template through the variables attribute.  Yet I have to figure out how to access a dictionary on the template that has been passed through the variables attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after comment reading I really do think you have to namespace your attributes.

If the template resource is the same (same path in destination) it can't work (or it will loop updating and you'll end up with only one file).

For some deployments we do something like:

```
node['company']['apps']['app1']['simple_value1']="value1"
node['company']['apps']['app1']['simple_value2']="value2"
node['company']['apps']['app2']['simple_value1']="value3"
node['company']['apps']['app2']['simple_value2']="value4"
```

And in recipe we render the template using something like:

```
template 'app1/WEB-INF/web.xml' do
  source 'web.xml.erb'
  cookbook 'app-templates' # specify the source cookbook to avoid duplicating the template file over many cookbooks
  variables({
     :app_name => 'app1',
     :app_vars => node['company']['apps']['app1']
  })
end
```

In the template we use `@app_vars['simple_value1']` and `@app_vars['simple_value2']` and sometimes we iterate over `node['company']['apps'][@app_name]` child attributes to use the same template for different use cases with different number of values for each app.

exemple .erb:

```
Any line of fixed text

<% node['company']['apps'][@app_name].each do |name, value| -%>
key_<%= name %>=<%= value %>
<% end -%>

Rest of file...
```

(Simplified here but I think it's enough to get the concept)

Comment: I was close! haha. Thanx for the answer, this is what I was looking for. Well, I was looking for a way to allow attributes to be overwritten by cookbook at converge time but that is not possible. Thanx!

Comment: You may use lazy evaluation, but it won't work as expected (unless you change the attribute inside a ruby_block)